# Procedure to check annual date

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, stored-procedures

I'm trying to create a procedure to verify annual dates. The date is stored one time in the BD, but in the calendar on my winform it shows annually(I use annually bolded dates in C#). So what I want to do with the query, is to check is the month and the day are like the date stored in the table, but does not work. This is my query:

```
SELECT IdCalendar,
        Description,
        DateCalendar,
        Annualy
FROM Calendar
WHERE
(DATEPART(MONTH,DateCalendar) like DATEPART(MONTH,@DateCalendar)) AND
(DATEPART(DAY,DateCalendar) like DATEPART(DAY,@DateCalendar))
```

And for example, my stored DateCalendar is '2015-12-04', and I my paramenter @DateCalendar is '2016-12-04'. Any idea about how to do a better query?

**EDIT**

The query does not have any error or warning. Just returns 0 rows. And my DateCalendar is stored as DateTime.

The SP:

```
CREATE PROC [dbo].[usp_app_Calendar_Search]
@DateCalendar DATETIME,
@Result     SMALLINT OUTPUT,
@Message      VARCHAR(1000) OUTPUT

AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @vResult SMALLINT, @vMessage VARCHAR(1000)
 SELECT  @vResult = 0, @vMessage = ''

 BEGIN TRY
 IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Calendar WHERE DateCalendar = @DateCalendar)
 BEGIN
        IF(@DateCalendar = 0) SET @DateCalendar = NULL
SELECT IdCalendar,
        Description,
        DateCalendar,
        Annualy
FROM Calendar
WHERE
(DATEPART(MONTH,DateCalendar) like DATEPART(MONTH,@DateCalendar)) AND
(DATEPART(DAY,DateCalendar) like DATEPART(DAY,@DateCalendar))
SET @vResult = 1
        SET @vMessage = 'Done'
    END
    ELSE BEGIN

        SET @vResult = 0
        SET @vMessage  = 'Error.'

    END
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH

    SET @vResult = -1
    SET @vMessage = 'Error: ' + ERROR_MESSAGE() + ' Line: ' + CAST(ERROR_LINE() AS VARCHAR)

END CATCH

SELECT @Result = @vResult, @Message = @vMessage
END
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `WHERE
DATEPART(MONTH,DateCalendar) = DATEPART(MONTH,@DateCalendar) AND
DATEPART(DAY,DateCalendar) = DATEPART(DAY,@DateCalendar)`

Comment: I had tried with that  but doesn't work @lad2025

Comment: Be specific. Bad results/No results at all/error/warning? How do you store your `DateCalendar` DATE/DATETIME/VARCHAR?

Comment: @lad2025 I edited my question!

Comment: Share entire stored procedure. Do you pass arguments correctly?

Comment: `IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Calendar WHERE DateCalendar = @DateCalendar)`???

Comment: It is to verify is the date exists

Comment: I just want to check if the month and the day are like the date stored because the year is gonna change always because are annual dates, like 2015-12-04, 2016-04-12,2017-12-04, etc

Comment: When you use IF your code always go to ELSE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with `IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Calendar WHERE DateCalendar = @DateCalendar)`. I rewrite your SP:

```
CREATE PROC [dbo].[usp_app_Calendar_Search]
   @DateCalendar DATETIME,
   @Result       SMALLINT OUTPUT,
   @Message      VARCHAR(1000) OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @vResult SMALLINT = 0
        ,@vMessage VARCHAR(1000) = '';

IF(@DateCalendar = 0) SET @DateCalendar = NULL;

BEGIN TRY   
  SELECT IdCalendar,
        Description,
        DateCalendar,
        Annualy
  FROM Calendar
  WHERE DATEPART(MONTH,DateCalendar) = DATEPART(MONTH,@DateCalendar)
    AND DATEPART(DAY,DateCalendar) = DATEPART(DAY,@DateCalendar);

  IF @@ROWCOUNT > 0
    SELECT @vResult = 1, @vMessage = 'Done'
  ELSE 
    SELECT @vResult = 0, @vMessage  = 'Error.';
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    SET @vResult = -1
    SET @vMessage = 'Error: ' + ERROR_MESSAGE() + ' Line: ' 
                    + CAST(ERROR_LINE() AS VARCHAR)
END CATCH

SELECT @Result = @vResult, @Message = @vMessage;

END
```

**EDIT:**

Now the `WHERE` condition is not-SARGable so it means that query optimizer will skip index on `DateCalendar` column (if exists any).

You can use computed columns like [@Tom Page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3338171/tom-page) suggested in comment:

```
ALTER TABLE Calendar ADD MonthCalendar AS DATEPART(MONTH,DateCalendar);
ALTER TABLE Calendar ADD DayCalendar AS DATEPART(day,DateCalendar);

/*Create Index on Calculated Columns for Month and day*/
 CREATE INDEX IX_Calendar_Month_Day ON Calendar(MonthCalendar , DayCalendar); 

/*Use Computed Column Index in W*/ 
DECLARE @DateCalendar datetime = '2015-12-25';

SELECT IdCalendar, Description, DateCalendar, Annualy 
FROM Calendar 
WHERE MonthCalendar = DATEPART(MONTH,@DateCalendar) 
  AND DayCalendar   = DATEPART(DAY,@DateCalenda);
```

Comment: great! I think the same with you comment IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Calendar WHERE DateCalendar = @DateCalendar) thanks! :D

Comment: Try this
/*Create Calculated Columns for Month and day*/
ALTER TABLE Calendar ADD  MonthCalendar AS DATEPART(MONTH,DateCalendar) 
ALTER TABLE Calendar  ADD  DayCalendar   AS DATEPART(day,DateCalendar) 
GO
/*Create Index on Calculated Columns for Month and day*/
CREATE INDEX IX_Calendar_Month_Day  ON Calendar(MonthCalendar , DayCalendar )
GO
/*Use Computed Column Index in W*/
DECLARE @DateCalendar datetime = '2015-12-25'
SELECT IdCalendar, Description, DateCalendar, Annualy 
FROM Calendar
WHERE MonthCalendar = DATEPART(month,@DateCalendar)  AND DayCalendar = DATEPART(DAY,@DateCalenda